# How to use parameter in LIKE STRING SQL in VB6

Tags: sql, string, parameters, vb6, code-injection

Now I am having a problem with "LIKE" String SQL in VB6. I want to prevent SQL Injection. Here is my code:

```
sqlText= "Select  *"
sqlText = sqlText & " From MyStudent"
sqlText = sqlText & " Where Name LIKE ?"

Set dbRec = new ADODB.RecordSet
Set dbCmd = new ADODB.Command

With dbCmd
.ActiveConnection = dbCon
.CommandType = adCmdText
.CommandText = SqlText
End with

dbCmd.Parameters.Append dbCmd.CreateParameter("PNMKM", adVarChar, adParamInput, 20)
dbCmd.Parameters("PNMKM").Value = "'%" & Trim$(inpNMKM.Text) & "%'"
```

It can't not run. 
Help me,
Thank you so much

Comment: What bad thing happens when you run this?

Comment: Don't quote the parameter value (you wouldn't do this with `=` instead of `LIKE`, right?). Change it to `"%" & Trim$(inpNMKM.Text) & "%"`

Comment: I scare that it will have problem with SQL injection. I wanna to try how to prevent it.

Comment: Parameters prevent sql injection (barring crazy code that builds dynamic sql from them). You're safe.

Comment: however, I can not use "LIKE ?". how to use parameter with "LIKE" statement?

Comment: Did you try removing the single quotes like I suggested?

Answer (score 2):

Try run this code:

```
sqlText= "Select  *"
sqlText = sqlText & " From MyStudent"
sqlText = sqlText & " Where Name LIKE CONCAT('%', ? ,'%')"

Set dbRec = new ADODB.RecordSet
Set dbCmd = new ADODB.Command

With dbCmd
.ActiveConnection = dbCon
.CommandType = adCmdText
.CommandText = SqlText
End with

dbCmd.Parameters.Append dbCmd.CreateParameter("PNMKM", adVarChar, adParamInput, 20)
dbCmd.Parameters("PNMKM").Value = Trim$(inpNMKM.Text)
```

Used CONCAT function in SQL instead of adding % sign on addParameter.

Comment: It also has problem :(

Comment: Can I see the error message apperared when you test that code?

Comment: no error message however, it doesn't have any record is displayed although it exits. Now, I know how to fix it. It is simple: Don't quote the parameter value. Thank you so much